# Suppress the same warning from being repeated?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

Using MinGW (GCC) on Windows, when a single header file is included by multiple source files, if the header has a #warning or "#pragma message", it's repeated multiple times, despite that warning having already been reported.

Is there a way to ensure that a #warning or #pragma is only shown *once* per compile, so as to not get spammed with messages?

I don't want to hide the warning, just repeated occurrences of the same warning.

The headers with the #warnings and "#pragma message"s are include-guarded properly already, so I don't understand why the #warning repeats itself.

Comment: Are you compiling the headers multiple times in different translation units?  That is, do you compile multiple source files that include the same header?

Comment: *The headers with the #warnings and "#pragma message"s are include-guarded properly already, so I don't understand why the #warning repeats itself.* because they are *included* in multiple translations (or sources you compile).

Comment: You're looking for GCC's equivalent to Microsoft's `#pragma warning(once : xxxx )`?

Comment: If you're using an IDE, you can graphically group the warnings. That's not a real answer, I know, but it could mitigate the issue...

Comment: @Carl: Yeah, when I "rebuild all" I get spammed alot from "#pragma message()" I've scattered throughout the code. The ones in the header files get repeated multiple times, because they get included from multiple different source files.

Comment: @Justin: '*slaps forehead*' Oh right, I forgot for a moment how the inclusion guards work, and was thinking for half a second that they ensure the header is only included once per "project", instead of once per source file. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Borealid: I am use using an IDE - QtCreator, and I don't think it has that ability, though I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm not sure. I don't think so. Doesn't #pragma warning() disable a specific built-in compiler warning? I'm talking about #warnings that I myself have in the code, using #warning.

Comment: @CodyGray well, you could file a feature request with the QtCreator devs. otherwise, you could move those bits to the cpp if all else fails. sorry, I can't offer much help bc I usually work with VS when developing on windows. the good news is there are people with much more knowledge about that toolset than myself =)

Answer (score 1):

In your header mycode.h: #define WARN_ME_OF_THIS

In your code file mycode.c:
#include "mycode.h"

```
                        #ifdef WARN_ME_OF_THIS

                        #warning WARNING! THIS HAS HAPPENED

                        #endif
```

mycode.h may get included in multiple file but mycode.c is only compiled once so the warning only appears once.  You can put the #ifdef, #warning, #endif anywhere in mycode.c so I put it discretely at the end.

Comment: This is a decent answer, but I think it could be improved if you added a more comprehensive code example.